# Publish Visual Studio project causes error (while project is build and running correctly)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

This is the error I get when I am publishing my code in Visual Studio.

However my code is working fine

> Copying file obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\angular\controller\RTDUserProfileApp.js to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\angular\controller\RTDUserProfileApp.js failed.
>   Could not find file 'obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\angular\controller\RTDUserProfileApp.js'

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your .csproj file includes a file that is no longer in the project (i.e. has been deleted at some point). If RTDUserProfileApp.js is no longer part of your project open up the .csproj and remove the `<Compile Include=<offending file name> />` line.

Comment: RTDUserProfileApp this file is part of project if iam removing this file path from .scproj . it show same error for other files which are also included in project

Answer (score 0):

Open the .csproj file in notepad and verify the path of RTDUserProfileApp.js 
It could be that the .js file has been moved to a different folder from file explorer but not updated in .csproj

Comment: 3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3007,5): Error : Copying file obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\EntityFramework.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\EntityFramework.dll failed. Could not find file 'obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\EntityFramework.dll'.
3>

Comment: i have removed path from .csproj file now it is giving this errror

Comment: Looks like there should be EntityFramework.dll in the bin file. which is missing.